NestJS PostgreSQL SSL Connection AWS RDS
I have an AWS RDS for PostgreSQL, and I want to preform SSL connection in order to encrypt data in transit. I've configures it like so:
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: envVar.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: envVar.POSTGRES_PORT,
  username: envVar.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: envVar.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  database: envVar.POSTGRES_DB,
  ssl: true
})

But I got: Error: self-signed certificate in certificate chain
I've read in the documentation that I need to install rds-ca-rsa2048-g1.pem and use it.
What I dont understand is how to use it, and where to save the file? Should it be version controlled, in a configmap or a secret?

Does this answer your question? cannot connect an SSL secured database to typeorm

You can check it into version control, you can take it from the env, you can retrieve it from a parameter store, load it from S3, really does not matter. Secret would be a bad place because it is not a secret.
